# Angular 2 / Rxjs : do I really need to unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, rxjs

I understand that I must unsubscribe certains Observable (ie: Observables that have **infinite** value) when Components are destroyed in order to prevent memory leaks. I do not need to do that for **finite** Observables as they will complete and automatically `unsubscribe`.

But if I create an **infinite** `Observable` in my component (for example `FormGroup.valueChanges`, or `QueryList.changes`), this one will be destroyed with the component that contains it, so I **think** that they will be no memory leak even if I **do not** unsubscribe from it.

Here is a simple example:

```
@Component({})
export class DummyComponent {
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            firstName: [''],
            lastName: ['']
        });
        this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(
            x => console.log(x)
        );
    }
}
```

Here, I do not `unsubscribe` from `this.form.valueChanges`; when my component is destroyed, the `this.form.valueChanges` will be destroyed too.

Will there be a memory leak in this case?

Comment: Have you tried to add an complete callback to subscribe(...) and checked if it gets called when the component is destroyed?

Comment: I did, and it is not called (I only did the test with `this.form.valueChanges`).

Comment: I guess then it's better but not necessary to unsubscribe. I wouldn't expect a memory leak because the when the component is destroyed, it will get garbage collected, and your subscription with it. If you subscribe or pass the subscription outside of the component (for example a service) then this might prevent the component from being GCed, but if all is within the component it shouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Babar had mention, you need to do the unsubscribe in order to stop those subscriptions to continue watching for changes.

For your particular case I think that you have a point.

One thing I do when I have a lot of subscriptions in the same component is the following.

First I create "subscriptions", an empty Array of Subscription type.

```
private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
```

Then every time I need to do subscribe I push it into the array

```
this.subscriptions.push(this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(x => console.log(x)));
```

And in the ngOnDestroy I unsubscribe to every subscription inside the array.

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscriptions.forEach((elem) => { elem.unsubscribe(); })
}
```

Comment: You can add subscriptions to each other with the subscription.add() method. Then you only need to unsubscribe the top subscription.

Answer (score 3):

When your component is destroyed your subscribers are not they still waiting for any event came to them it will cost memory as well sometimes it may disturb your logics as well. for example router events subscription it will trigger everywhere in your app and execute the code you did inside subscription.

I second case if you switch between components and never unsubscribed your app will be hang up after a bunch of time because whenever you load the component new subscribers bind up.

```
@Component({})
export class DummyComponent implements OnDestroy {
 form: FormGroup;
 subscription: Subscription; // from rxjs
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        firstName: [''],
        lastName: ['']
    });
    this.subscription = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(
        x => console.log(x)
    );
 }

 ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```